# Es posible con React tener componentes de la manera siguiente:

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Quiero hacer algo como lo que se puede hacer en vue, en el index.html dentro de #app tener una estructura asi:

```
<div id="app">
 <mi-componente prop="algo" prop="otracosa"></mi-componente>
</div>
```

he visto varios tutoriales donde lo hacen de la siguente manera

```
import App from './js/Components/App.jsx';
ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

y dentro de app meten los componentes, pero eso no quiero... yo quiere meter los componentes a mi antojo en el html ya que usare codeigniter y solo ocupo uno que otro componente no elaborar todo un sitio con react...

Comment: Supongo que si usas el script directamente del CDN te vale para lo que comentas: https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

Answer (score 0):

A tu pregunta la respuesta es SI, por supuesto, no de ésa manera exacta a cómo lo harías con Vue o Angular, pero no lo necesitas. De hecho solo tienes que añadir el script a tu html del cdn oficial: https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html.

A partir de ahí cómo uses las clases y accesos al DOM `is up to you`.

Te lo comento así porque lo he aplicado en varios proyectos, insertar scripts de react para partes pequeñas de la aplicacion, voy a tratar de ponerte un ejemplo.

Podrias tener una lista en alguna parte de la web y en vez de inserta

```html
... 
   ...
      ...
         <div id="mi-lista-react"></div>
```

Y luego tener en la etiqueta script algo así:

```js
<script type="text/babel">
const lista = [1,2,3,4]
class MiLista extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<ul>{lista.map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}</ul>);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Lista />,
    document.getElementById('mi-lista-react')
);
</script>
```

Y así sucesivamente ;)

Documentación en inglés: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Ejemplos: https://gist.github.com/gaearon/faa67b76a6c47adbab04f739cba7ceda

Comment: Hola Amigo gracias por tu respuesta pero como le pasas propiedades?? mira lo que quiero es desde code igniter traer de mysql una lista de cursos y desde un foreach pasarle parametros al componente ejemplo:


`<?php foreach($cursos as $curso): ?>

 <cursos id="<?=$curso['id']?>" nombre="<?=$curso['nombre']?>" imagen="<?=$curso['img']?>" > </cursos>

<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Si tienes la lista en la variable $cursos, tienes que pasarla al JS, yo traería los datos desde el JS o crearía una variable global que pueda leer en JS, por ejemplo a través de `window`, por ej. `window.listaCursos`, no estoy seguro de cómo setear esa var global en php para luego poder leerla o si hay un approach mejor.